# Switching View in methods in XCode 4

Tags: ios, methods, switching

I am using XCode 4.4 and making an app with storyboard.
I want to switch to another view in a method of a view.
I want to achieve the same functionality as switching
view on storyboard by modal,inside the method.
So far I am using the following code:

```
-(IBAction)xplus:(id)sender
{
    x++;
     if(x>30)
    {
           ViewController_2 *viewControllerx = [[ViewController_2 alloc] init];
         [self presentViewController:viewControllerx animated:YES completion:nil];
     }

 }
```

When the view is supposed to change ie when x becomes greater than 30
a Black Screen appears instead of the required view. I personally think my code is correct but why it shows a black screen?

How can I to achieve the same functionality as switching view on storyboard by modal,inside the method ?

Comment: Use a modal transition, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not working out probably because you are not not using the `.xib` file with the view controller that you want to go to and using storyboard.

Anyways let me give you an easy and efficient method to perform the task.

Step 1: Go to storyboard of your project and click on the `View Controller` to which you want to go in your method i.e. `ViewController_2.Click` on the inspector icon(It is the 4th one). In the identifier field type a name eg: `second`.

Step 2: Use the following lines in your method to create a instance of `ViewController_2` using the `initiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` method and to modal to it.

```
ViewController_2 *v2=[self.storyboard initiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"]; [self presentModalViewController:v2.animated:YES];
```

Now the app will go to(create instance of) the `ViewController` having the same Identifier as the one given as argument i.e. `second`.